# How to create unique IDs when ranging over data in Golang and use in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, go, local-storage, pipeline

I am getting data from the server and iterating over it to create a table and then I am using a form to store an id to local storage using javascript. Here is code snippet

```
<table>
    <tr><th>Product ID</th></tr>
    {{range .}}
    <td ><form onsubmit="save_data()" action="/" method="get"><button class="btn btn-info pid" id="pid" name="{{.puid}}" value="{{.puid}}">Update</button></form></td>
    {{end}}
<table>

<script>

function save_data() {
  var input = document.getElementByID("pid");
  localStorage.setItem("id", input.value); 

}   

</script>
```

However every time, no matter of which table row's "update" button I click, everytime only the ID of the first table row element is getting stored. 
Is there a way I can generate unique IDs and reference it in Javascript when ranging over the data.
Thanks

Comment: Also asked [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/dNaoKtBEQp0/discussion). Next time please take care to mention other venues you've used to post your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop You have

```
<button class="..." id="pid" name="{{.puid}}" value="{{.puid}}">Update</button>
```

which means that all buttons have `id` attribute whith the same value `pid`. This is an bug as `id`-s must be unique in the document. And when you call

```
document.getElementById("pid");
```

the first element matching the `id="pid"` is returned. That explains why "only the ID of the first table row element is getting stored".

To create unique id for each row you could use something like

```
{{range $index, $value := .}}
...<button class="..." id="pid{{$index}}" name="{{$value.puid}}" value="{{$value.puid}}">Update</button>...
{{end}}
```

but then you have a problem how to know which form was submitted when your `save_data()` event fires. To solve this you could send the current form or row id as a parameter, something like

```
{{range $index, $value := .}}
<td><form onsubmit="save_data(this, {{$index}})" action="/" method="get">...</form></td>
{{end}}

function save_data(form, rowno) {
  var input = document.getElementById("pid"+rowno);
  localStorage.setItem("id", input.value); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!. This is an awesome solution. I was trying to work out a javascript solution. You just saved my day!.